# HTML form posts fine with IE but fails to send (most) values with Firefox and Chrome?

Tags: php, html, forms

Relatively simple form - nothing fancy -

Post goes thru exactly as expected with I.E. v11 and Edge .

However - with Chrome and Firefox - ONLY two hidden fields come thru, the rest of the post results are null/empty.

Convert to GET and I get the same results.

This is a straightforward HTML form using a submit button, and the action is a straightforward php script that collects the field values and inserts them into a MySQL database. Old school stuff.

I'm bewildered at this point.

Comment: No code? Doesn't help us to answer the question if we can't diagnose what's causing the problem.

Comment: I discovered the root problem. It worked in IE and Edge but failed in Firefox and Chrome, thoroughly confusing me. After all else failed, I plowed line by line and discovered that the doc model 'nodes' were off by one step. Using UltraEdit, the form would collapse to a </div> BEFORE the closing </form> tag which was collapsing with the <row> tag above the initial <form> tag. 

I relocated the <form> tag and it was all good. Seems IE and Edge could handle the malformed HTML - while Firefox and Chrome choked on it. I use a builder app for the visual design and it bit me (first time ever).